# foreign key issues in GET METHOD in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

i have a table users which have a column with foreign key... when i post a request in postman of get or get by id it shows the foreign key table data also. i want to show only "USERS" table data only.

```
   using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using System.Web.Http.Description;
    using Taylor.Models;

        namespace Taylor.API_Controller
    {
        [RoutePrefix("api/Suit")]
        public class SuitController : ApiController
        {
                public TaylorEntities db = new TaylorEntities();
                // GET api/<controller>
            public List<Suit> GetAllSuit()
           {
                return db.Suit.ToList();
            }
```

here is a class

```
namespace Taylor.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Users
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Users()
        {
            this.AppUser = new HashSet<AppUser>();
        }
    
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int UserRoleId { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedAt { get; set; }
        public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AppUser> AppUser { get; set; }
        public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
    }
}
```

in POSTMAN when i request a GET METHOD https://localhost:44311/api/User/6

it shows this much data

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "AppUser": [],
    "UserRole": {
        "$id": "2",
        "Users": [
            {
                "$ref": "1"
            },
            {
                "$id": "3",
                "AppUser": [
                    {
                        "$id": "4",
                        "Location": {
                            "$id": "5",
                            "AppUser": [
                                {
                                    "$ref": "4"
                                },
                                {
                                    "$id": "6",
                                    "Location": {
                                        "$ref": "5"
                                    },
                                    "Users": {
                                        "$ref": "3"
                                    },
                                    "Customer": [],
                                    "AppUserId": 4,
                                    "AdminUserId": 1,
                                    "StartDate": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                    "EndDate": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                    "LocationId": 1,
                                    "City": "Lahore",
                                    "RegisterDate": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                    "IsActive": true,
                                    "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                    "CreatedBy": 1,
                                    "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                    "ModifiedBy": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "$id": "7",
                                    "Location": {
                                        "$ref": "5"
                                    },
                                    "Users": {
                                        "$ref": "3"
                                    },
                                    "Customer": [],
                                    "AppUserId": 5,
                                    "AdminUserId": 1,
                                    "StartDate": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                    "EndDate": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                    "LocationId": 1,
                                    "City": "Islamabad",
                                    "RegisterDate": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                    "IsActive": true,
                                    "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                    "CreatedBy": 1,
                                    "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                    "ModifiedBy": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "$id": "8",
                                    "Location": {
                                        "$ref": "5"
                                    },
                                    "Users": {
                                        "$id": "9",
                                        "AppUser": [
                                            {
                                                "$ref": "8"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "UserRole": {
                                            "$ref": "2"
                                        },
                                        "UserId": 3,
                                        "Name": "Haider",
                                        "PhoneNumber": "0347-8526942",
                                        "Email": "haider@yahoo.com",
                                        "UserRoleId": 1,
                                        "IsActive": true,
                                        "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                        "CreatedBy": 1,
                                        "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                        "ModifiedBy": 1
                                    },
                                    "Customer": [
                                        {
                                            "$id": "10",
                                            "AppUser": {
                                                "$ref": "8"
                                            },
                                            "Nap": [
                                                {
                                                    "$id": "11",
                                                    "Customer": {
                                                        "$ref": "10"
                                                    },
                                                    "NapDetails": [
                                                        {
                                                            "$id": "12",
                                                            "Nap": {
                                                                "$ref": "11"
                                                            },
                                                            "Suit": {
                                                                "$id": "13",
                                                                "NapDetails": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "$ref": "12"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "SuitId": 1,
                                                                "Title": "Pent",
                                                                "IsActive": true,
                                                                "CreatedAt": "2021-07-25T00:00:00",
                                                                "CreatedBy": 1,
                                                                "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-25T00:00:00",
                                                                "ModifiedBy": 1
                                                            },
                                                            "NapDetailsId": 1,
                                                            "SuitId": 1,
                                                            "Measurement": "62,25,2514",
                                                            "NapId": 1,
                                                            "IsActive": true,
                                                            "CreatedAt": "2021-07-29T00:00:00",
                                                            "CreatedBy": 1,
                                                            "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-29T00:00:00",
                                                            "ModifiedBy": 1
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "$id": "14",
                                                            "Nap": {
                                                                "$ref": "11"
                                                            },
                                                            "Suit": {
                                                                "$id": "15",
                                                                "NapDetails": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "$ref": "14"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "SuitId": 2,
                                                                "Title": "Shirt",
                                                                "IsActive": true,
                                                                "CreatedAt": "2021-07-25T00:00:00",
                                                                "CreatedBy": 1,
                                                                "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-25T00:00:00",
                                                                "ModifiedBy": 1
                                                            },
                                                            "NapDetailsId": 2,
                                                            "SuitId": 2,
                                                            "Measurement": "fbsh,2514785",
                                                            "NapId": 1,
                                                            "IsActive": true,
                                                            "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                                            "CreatedBy": 1,
                                                            "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                                            "ModifiedBy": 1
                                                        }
                                                    ],
                                                    "NapId": 1,
                                                    "CustomerId": 1,
                                                    "ImageUrl": "sgjakdvaksgfew",
                                                    "IsActive": true,
                                                    "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                                    "CreatedBy": 1,
                                                    "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                                    "ModifiedBy": 1
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "$id": "16",
                                                    "Customer": {
                                                        "$ref": "10"
                                                    },
                                                    "NapDetails": [],
                                                    "NapId": 4,
                                                    "CustomerId": 1,
                                                    "ImageUrl": "sgjakdvaksgfew",
                                                    "IsActive": true,
                                                    "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                                    "CreatedBy": 1,
                                                    "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                                    "ModifiedBy": 1
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "CustomerId": 1,
                                            "AppUserId": 3,
                                            "PhoneNumber": "0321-8521475",
                                            "CustomerName": "Talha",
                                            "Address": "Multan",
                                            "IsActive": true,
                                            "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                            "CreatedBy": 1,
                                            "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                            "ModifiedBy": 1
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "$id": "17",
                                            "AppUser": {
                                                "$ref": "8"
                                            },
                                            "Nap": [],
                                            "CustomerId": 3,
                                            "AppUserId": 3,
                                            "PhoneNumber": "0321-8521475",
                                            "CustomerName": "Abu Bakar",
                                            "Address": "Multan",
                                            "IsActive": true,
                                            "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                            "CreatedBy": 1,
                                            "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                                            "ModifiedBy": 1
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "AppUserId": 3,
                                    "AdminUserId": 3,
                                    "StartDate": "2021-07-26T00:00:00",
                                    "EndDate": "2021-07-31T00:00:00",
                                    "LocationId": 1,
                                    "City": "karachi",
                                    "RegisterDate": "2001-12-15T00:00:00",
                                    "IsActive": true,
                                    "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T00:00:00",
                                    "CreatedBy": 1,
                                    "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T00:00:00",
                                    "ModifiedBy": 1
                                }
                            ],
                            "Location1": {
                                "$ref": "5"
                            },
                            "Location2": {
                                "$ref": "5"
                            },
                            "LocationId": 1,
                            "Lat": 0.254,
                            "Long": 0.568,
                            "IsActive": true,
                            "CreatedAt": "2021-07-15T00:00:00",
                            "CreatedBy": 1,
                            "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-15T00:00:00",
                            "ModifiedBy": 1
                        },
                        "Users": {
                            "$ref": "3"
                        },
                        "Customer": [],
                        "AppUserId": 1,
                        "AdminUserId": 1,
                        "StartDate": "2021-06-15T00:00:00",
                        "EndDate": "2021-07-15T00:00:00",
                        "LocationId": 1,
                        "City": "multan",
                        "RegisterDate": "2001-06-24T00:00:00",
                        "IsActive": true,
                        "CreatedAt": "2021-07-15T00:00:00",
                        "CreatedBy": 1,
                        "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-15T00:00:00",
                        "ModifiedBy": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "$ref": "6"
                    },
                    {
                        "$ref": "7"
                    }
                ],
                "UserRole": {
                    "$ref": "2"
                },
                "UserId": 1,
                "Name": "Khakan",
                "PhoneNumber": "0300-1234567",
                "Email": "khakan@gmail.com",
                "UserRoleId": 1,
                "IsActive": true,
                "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T00:00:00",
                "CreatedBy": 1,
                "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T00:00:00",
                "ModifiedBy": 1
            },
            {
                "$ref": "9"
            },
            {
                "$id": "18",
                "AppUser": [],
                "UserRole": {
                    "$ref": "2"
                },
                "UserId": 4,
                "Name": "Shahzad",
                "PhoneNumber": "0347-8526942",
                "Email": "shahzad@hotmail.com",
                "UserRoleId": 1,
                "IsActive": true,
                "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T00:00:00",
                "CreatedBy": 1,
                "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T00:00:00",
                "ModifiedBy": 1
            },
            {
                "$id": "19",
                "AppUser": [],
                "UserRole": {
                    "$ref": "2"
                },
                "UserId": 7,
                "Name": "Mr. Johny",
                "PhoneNumber": "0300-6589321",
                "Email": "johny@hotmail.com",
                "UserRoleId": 1,
                "IsActive": true,
                "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                "CreatedBy": 1,
                "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                "ModifiedBy": 1
            },
            {
                "$id": "20",
                "AppUser": [],
                "UserRole": {
                    "$ref": "2"
                },
                "UserId": 8,
                "Name": "Usman Khan",
                "PhoneNumber": "0321-9632584",
                "Email": "usman@gmail.com",
                "UserRoleId": 1,
                "IsActive": true,
                "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                "CreatedBy": 1,
                "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
                "ModifiedBy": 1
            }
        ],
        "UserRoleId": 1,
        "Title": "Admin",
        "IsActive": true,
        "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T00:00:00",
        "CreatedBy": 1,
        "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T00:00:00",
        "ModifiedBy": 1
    },
    "UserId": 6,
    "Name": "Awais",
    "PhoneNumber": "0321-9632584",
    "Email": "awais@hotmail.com",
    "UserRoleId": 1,
    "IsActive": true,
    "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
    "CreatedBy": 1,
    "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
    "ModifiedBy": 1
}
```

but i want only this one

```
"UserId": 6,
        "Name": "Awais",
        "PhoneNumber": "0321-9632584",
        "Email": "awais@hotmail.com",
        "UserRoleId": 1,
        "IsActive": true,
        "CreatedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
        "CreatedBy": 1,
        "ModifiedAt": "2021-07-26T04:18:42.893",
        "ModifiedBy": 1
    }
```

Comment: Share your Api Code here for better understanding

Comment: using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using Taylor.Models;

namespace Taylor.API_Controller
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/Suit")]
    public class SuitController : ApiController
    {
        public TaylorEntities db = new TaylorEntities();
        // GET api/<controller>
        public List<Suit> GetAllSuit()
        {
            return db.Suit.ToList();
        }

Comment: i have updated the question wuth code ... review it

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more information on what framework you are using on the backend side to interact with the database.

If entity framework has been used, probably the query to get the result from the database has "Include" extension method, that's why it is fetching the foreign data too.

Comment: using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using Taylor.Models;

namespace Taylor.API_Controller
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/Suit")]
    public class SuitController : ApiController
    {
        public TaylorEntities db = new TaylorEntities();
        // GET api/<controller>
        public List<Suit> GetAllSuit()
        {
            return db.Suit.ToList();
        }

Comment: i have updated the question wuth code ... review it @suryanshu Singh

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb Still the data layer code is missing. Just paste the query which is being used to fetch the users. It would be something similar to context.Users.Where(...).ToList();

Comment: namespace Taylor.API_Controller
    {
        [RoutePrefix("api/Suit")]
        public class SuitController : ApiController
        {
                public TaylorEntities db = new TaylorEntities();
                // GET api/<controller>
            public List<Suit> GetAllSuit()
           {
                return db.Suit.ToList();
            }

Answer (score 0):

You can create new `User` like this for given `Id`

```
var user = conetxt.Users
.Select(u=> new User{ UserId = u.UserId, UserName = u.UserName, ...  })
.SingleOrDefault(u=>u.UserId == id);
```

If you want have `List<User>`

```
var user = conetxt.Users
.Select(u=> new User{ UserId = u.UserId, UserName = u.UserName, ...  })
.ToList();
```

It is suggested to use

> DTO

instead of `Model` for `Response` You should expose only required properties to the client